# Two coins are tossed independently where P(head occurs when coin $i$ is tossed) = $p_i$, $i=1,2$.

Tags: probability

Given that at least one head has occurred, the probability that the coin produce different outcome
a) $\frac{2p_{1}p_{2}}{p_{1}+p_{2}-2p_{1}p_{2}}$

b) $\frac{p_{1}+p_{2}-2p_{1}p_{2}}{p_{1}+p_{2}-p_{1}p_{2}}$

c) $\frac{2}{3}$

d) none of these.

I think the answer should be b) since $$P(\text{different outcome} | \text{at least one head has occurred}) = \frac{P(\textrm{different outcome}) \cap P(\textrm{at least one head})} {P(\textrm{at least one head})} = \frac{p_{1}(1-p_{2})+p_{2}(1-p_{1})}{p_{1}(1-p_{2})+p_{2}(1-p_{1})+p_{1}p_{2}}.$$

Comment: You seem to have the correct answer.

Comment: So it is not $\frac{2}{3}$ right ? Somewhere I saw that since sample space of at least one head is {HH,TH , HT} and desired is it {TH,HT} so it is $\frac{2}{3}$. But in that case are'nt we assuming $p_{i}=\frac{1}{2}$ ?

Comment: You are correct, if we separate cases like the way you have done in your comment, we are assuming that $p_i = \frac{1}{2}$, because each of TH,HT,TT,HH gets the same weight, which is $0.25$