# at least one coin has occured then the probability that coin produced different result = (1)2P1p2p1+p2−2p1p2

Tags: probability, combinatorics, permutations, combinations

Two coins are tossed independently where $P($head occurs when coin $i$ is tossed $)=p_i$ , then  given that at least one coin has occured then the probability that coin produced different result =

(1)$\frac{2P_1p_2}{p_1+p_2-2p_1p_2}$

(2) $\frac{p_1+p_2-2p_1p_2}{P_1+p_2-p_1p_2}$

(3) $\frac{2}{3} $

(4) None these .

I think the correct answer is (b).

reasoning : 
Let $A=$at least one head  and $B=$different out come .

Now $P(A)=1-(1-p_1)(1-p_2)=p_1+p_2-p_1p_2 $ .

$P(B)=P($first one is head and second one tail$)+P($first outcome is tail and second outcome is head$)=p_1(1-p_2)+p_2(1-p_1) = p_1+p_2-2p_1p_2$ .

So required probability$ =P(B|A)=\frac{P(A\cap B)}{P(A)}=\frac{p_1+p_2-2p_1p_2}{p_1+p_2-p_1p_2}$ .

Is my solution correct ?

Comment: ' given that at least one coin has occured' ... that's a bit cryptic ... Are you just asking for the probability that the two coins have a different outcome?  Or should it be 'given that there is at least one head ...'?

Comment: Yes, your solution is correct. You may just add that $B\subset A$ to justify the fact that you wrote $P(A\cap B)=P(B)$.

Comment: @Bram28 , that is exactly why i asked the question . I'm not sure what the question meant at the first place . I asked the question to verify if what i'm thinking is correct . If you want the way around  i think the answer is  $\frac{p_1(1-p_2)}{p_1+p_2-p_1p_2}$

Comment: @SumanKundu Well, unfortunately I can't mind-read the intent of the person who created the original question. :P  But I can tell you that 'given that one coin occurred' says absolutely nothing ... so it's unlikely that the author meant to say that. So I like your interpretation of making that int 'given that at least one head occurred' ... in which case your work is correct and b is the correct answer ... and given that it *is* one of the answers provided would seem to be further confirmation that this would be what was really meant.

Comment: Thank you for input .  Yes sometimes problems related to counting needs clear clarification which is absent in the present problem .

Comment: Same question: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1758904/two-coins-are-tossed-independently-where-phead-occurs-when-coin-i-is-tossed.